# Combine DC voltages from solar panel and grid

Tags: power-supply, solar-cell

I have a large number of DC-powered devices: most of them can operate off 8-23V. I currently run them off a mains 12V power supply. What is the most efficient way to power them off the solar panels when the sun is shining, and off the mains power supply at night or in bad weather.

I can custom design switch mode power supplies, with FETs to switch between solar and power supply: but would work any better than using two big diodes?

Comment: How much power will diodes waste?

Comment: @Andyaka with 0.7V across the diode from a 12V supply, that's a 6% loss.

Comment: That sounds like the answer to your question then.

Comment: @Andyaka the whole point of using solar panels is to reduce energy consumption. Wasting 6% of mains power for 16 hours a day does not fit with that plan.

Comment: So, you have your answer then. What's the issue here?

Comment: I guess my question is, has anybody tried some other topology, and did it waste less power than that?

Comment: This is a Q and A site for a good reason. You ask a good Q and someone provides a good A. This isn't happening at the moment.